# RxJS & Firebase: Operating on a Stream Instead of Starting Another

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I'd like to assign a Firebase database node value to a variable by operating on a child node in an existing stream rather than starting a new one. So instead of...

```
(`threads/${threadId}/posts/${postId}`)
.subscribe(post => this.body = post.body)
```

Something like...

```
(`threads/${threadId}/posts`)
.subscribe(posts => {
    //Get the post with the key that correlates to postId
    //Assign the value of its body property to a string variable
})
```

Any ideas?